# non-volunteer logout when linking between server and client django apps

Tags: django, session, logout

I am building an app client and another app server (with mini flash games). I need to be logged on the client side to get a button which able an html page with an iFrame which in its turns ask to download the game inside it. so far so good.
On the server side the request from the client will need to check if the user exists, if it does it start to sending the game.
Well the game starts to be sent but stops and the client side is automatically logged out...
I breakpointed the logout method (@ **init**.py) but it does get there... Anyone did already get the same problem.
I am newbie on Django and maybe this is a know problem but I didn't find anything like so far..
Thanks!